# ¿Cómo hago que el resultado de mi bucle sea un solo string?

Tags: javascript

El bucle que estoy haciendo une 3 strings pero repitiendo la variable *lyric1* como ahí se ve cuando efectúo el `console.log`. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo hago que el resultado del bucle que ahí se genera se vuelva un string o concatenación?  [image: Imagen del Ejercicio que debo hacer]

```js
let lyric1= "let it be, "
let lyric2="whisper words of wisdom, "
let lyric3="there will be an answer, "
function sing(){
for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
  console.log(lyric1)
  if(i==3){
    console.log(lyric2)
  } else if(i==8){
    console.log(lyric3)
  }
}
}
sing()
```

Comment: Probablemente lo que estás buscando es imprimir _en una línea_ el resultado. Simplemente concatená los resultados en una nueva variable, e imprimí esa variable _recién al terminar el bucle_. ¡Sin complicaciones!

Comment: Sospecho que algo se quedó fuera de la imagen en los TIPS, pero de todos modos, parte de la tarea es leer la letra de la canción y por supuesto escucharla, pues el ejemplo dado, no corresponde totalmente con las lineas que debe retornar la función Sing().  Ojo con eso, tomado en cuenta en mi respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Puede realizar una concatenación como la siguiente: el resultado final estará en la variable song.

```
let song ="";
let lyric1= "let it be, "
let lyric2="whisper words of wisdom, "
let lyric3="there will be an answer, "
  function sing(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
      song += lyric1;
      if(i===3){
      song += lyric2;
      } else if(i===8){
      song += lyric3;
      }
    }
    return song;
  }
```

Comment: @williamrb: no debes tocar el código de la respuesta, salvo que sea para dar mejor formato. Si ves errores en ella, debes dejar un comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, ya escuchaste la canción y leiste la letra cierto?
Estos son los coros que se repiten en ese lapso de tiempo 3:10 a 3:54:

```
Let it be, let it be, let it be, yeah, let it be 
There will be an answer 
Let it be
 
Let it be, let it be, let it be, yeah, let it be 
There will be an answer 
Let it be

Let it be, let it be, let it be, yeah, let it be 
Whisper words of wisdom 
Let it be
```

En tu definición de la función Sing(), debes crear un arreglo con cada linea de texto de los coros ( de esa parte de la canción) y concatenarlo, cuidando de dejar el separador de nueva línea "\n" (estético no más, bien puede ser un espacio)

```js
function Sing(){

    const lyrics = [
        "Let it be, let it be",
        "Let it be, yeah, let it be",
        "Oh, there will be an answer",
        "Let it be",
        "Let it be, let it be",
        "Let it be, yeah, let it be",
        "Whisper words of wisdom",
        "Let it be"
    ];
    let concatenated = lyrics.join("\n");

    return concatenated;

}


console.log(Sing());
```

De otro modo, usando bucles, como el for que tienes en tu pregunta original:

```js
function Sing(){

    const lyrics = [
        "Let it be, let it be",
        "Let it be, yeah, let it be",
        "Oh, there will be an answer",
        "Let it be",
        "Let it be, let it be",
        "Let it be, yeah, let it be",
        "Whisper words of wisdom",
        "Let it be"
    ];

    let concatenated = lyrics[0];  //Aparte del bucle la primera linea, para poder agregar \n entre las sucesivas
    for (let i=1; i< lyrics.length; i++)
        concatenated = concatenated + "\n" + lyrics[i];

    return concatenated;

}


console.log(Sing());
```